# При создании сервиса на Linux нет соединения с БД Oracle

Tags: c#, linux, oracle

Возникла проблема при создании сервиса(systemd) в Linux для автоматического запуска Web App: нет никаких признаков соединения с Oracle БД.

Такая проблема только если запустить приложения как сервис, а если запускать в ручном режиме `dotnet webapp.dll` - работает без проблем, но такой запуск не приемлем. запуск ручного режима производится под рутом

**# dotnet webapp.dll**

Сервис для Linux создавался стандартно по хау-ту от MS и выглядит таким образом

> [Unit]
>
> Description=Web App running on CentOS 7
>
> [Service]
>
> WorkingDirectory=/sites/webapp
>
> Environment=ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:9090
>
> ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/dotnet /sites/webapp/webapp.dll
>
> Restart=always
>
> RestartSec=10 SyslogIdentifier=dotnet-example
>
> User=root
>
> environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
>
> [Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target

Если кто сталкивался, буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Можете добавить тип создания сервиса в *nix есть по меньшей мере 3 способа для этой цели: `systemd, upstart, sysv-style`

Comment: Кинь в вопрос файл запуска сервиса.

Comment: в вручную из какой лоуации запускаете, какие параметры и тд. тоже бы добавить